# Angular JS: I have empty page after success response from server

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I'm new at Angular (1.5 is used) and have the trouble with empty page after REST response from the server.

### HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link href="app-content/app.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
<body>

    <div class="jumbotron">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2">
                <div ng-class="{ 'alert': flash, 'alert-success': flash.type === 'success', 'alert-danger': flash.type === 'error' }" ng-if="flash" ng-bind="flash.message"></div>
                <div ng-view></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="credits text-center">
        <p>
            <a href="http://54.171.49.176:8081/swagger/index.html">Swagger REST documentation</a>
        </p>
    </div>

    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//code.angularjs.org/1.5.0/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="//code.angularjs.org/1.5.0/angular-route.js"></script>
    <script src="//code.angularjs.org/1.5.0/angular-cookies.js"></script>

    <script src="app.js"></script>
    <script src="app-services/authentication.service.js"></script>
    <script src="app-services/flash.service.js"></script>

    <script src="app-services/user.service.js"></script>

    <script src="home/home.controller.js"></script>
    <script src="login/login.controller.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

There are another html template at ng-view:

```
<h2>Hi {{vm.user.fullname}}!</h2>
<p>You're logged in!!</p>
<p>{{vm.error}}</p>
<h3>All registered users:</h3>
<div class="container">
    <table class="table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Email</th>
                <th>Full name</th>
                <th></th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="user in vm.allUsers">
                <td>{{user.email}}</td>
                <td>{{user.fullname}}</td>
            <td><a href="#" ng-click="vm.deleteUser(user.id)">Delete</a></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
<h3>Add new user:</h3>
<div class="container">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="first_name">Full name:</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="first_name" ng-model="vm.newUser.fullname"/>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="email">E-mail:</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="email" ng-model="vm.newUser.email"/>
    </div>
    <p><a href="#" class="btn btn-success" ng-click="vm.addNewUser()">Add new user</a></p>
</div>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p><a href="#/login" class="btn btn-primary">Logout</a></p>
```

### JS

#### Service and Controller

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('app')
        .controller('HomeController', HomeController);

    HomeController.$inject = ['UserService', '$rootScope'];
    function HomeController(UserService, $rootScope) {
        var vm = this;

        vm.user = null;
        vm.allUsers = [];
        vm.newUser = null;
        vm.error = null;
        vm.deleteUser = deleteUser;
        vm.addNewUser = addNewUser;

        ...

        function addNewUser() {
            UserService.Create(vm.newUser)
                .then(function (user) {
                    vm.allUsers.push(user);
                    vm.newUser = null;
                });
        }
    }

})();
```

Service method is `function Create(user) {
            return $http.post('http://localhost:8081/api/users', user).then(handleSuccess, handleError('Error creating user'));
        }`

#### Routing

```
config.$inject = ['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider'];
    function config($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
        $routeProvider
            .when('/', {
                controller: 'HomeController',
                templateUrl: 'home/home.view.html',
                controllerAs: 'vm'
            })

            .when('/login', {
                controller: 'LoginController',
                templateUrl: 'login/login.view.html',
                controllerAs: 'vm'
            })
            .otherwise({ redirectTo: '/login' });
    }
```

The user is returned successfully at debugger and pushed into users successfully too, but the page is empty instead of footer from index.html.
I tried to use `$scope` insteed of `vm`, but it is not helpful.

Any ideas how to fix it? I think I do not know something simple.

[image: Before adding/removing user]

[image: After adding/removing user]

Comment: Remove `.then(handleSuccess, handleError('Error creating user')` from your service

Comment: Are you trying to route to a different page after you get the response. What do you want to do after getting the response, just fill the array or do something else as well?

Comment: @CrazyMac I attached images, after delete operation result is same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested in one answer, From your service, just return the `$http.post` call which returns a promise back to the controller.

But you can handle success and response in the controller itself.

Please check the below code.

**Service:**

```
function Create(user) {
    return $http.post('http://localhost:8081/api/users', user);
}
```

Now, In your controller you can handle that promise and you will get the `success` and `error` call backs using `then`.

**Controller:**

```
function addNewUser() {
    UserService.Create(vm.newUser)
        .then(function success(user) { // this is success callback
            vm.allUsers.push(user);
            vm.newUser = null;
        },function error(user) // this is error callback
        {
            console.log(user);
        });
}
```

As you can see, you can even handle the error in the callback.

Since you are using `ng-route` and `routeProvider`, it mostly deals with `hashURL's`. so remove `href="#"` from the anchor tag.

**`<a href="#" class="btn btn-success" ng-click="vm.addNewUser()">Add new user</a>`**

Should be

**`<a class="btn btn-success" ng-click="vm.addNewUser()">Add new user</a>`**

Comment: I have the same: at debug mode push is work but after that, I see empty container

Comment: didn't get you, can you elaborate?

Comment: At my and your code I have the same behavior: the success function is work correctly, i.e. the user is added to vm.allUsers, but the page is empty after this operation. This is like the page is not rendered again.

Comment: after the user is pushed, the users listing is disappearing?

Comment: remove  `href="#"` from `<a href="#" class="btn btn-success" ng-click="vm.addNewUser()">Add new user</a>`

Answer (score 0):

Putting a then in the $http.post consume the promise in your service so its not returned to the caller of the service (your HomeController). You have to just return the promise by your service instead of consuming it. Use catch if you want to manage error in the service.

```js
function Create(user) {
    return $http.post('http://localhost:8081/api/users', user)
                .catch(handleError('Error creating user'));
}
```

Comment: Thank you but at controller I processed the response result, maybe you mean something another.